# When not given a link, use URL node

Tags: views, entities, uri

For a slideshow with banners, i've added the fields overlay-text and link-to. The link-to is the URL you go, if you click on the banner. It's al done & working in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) & [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

The user adds a node and has to set the URL by hand in the field link-to. Sometimes however, the banner has to point to a different URL or node.

How can i set the URL of the node when the field link-to is empty?

Comment: Can't you rewrite the output in the view field options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *No results behavior* on the field. Include the path field and use the field path token.

> [image: screenshot]

If there are no results, it picks the node URL.